# file is not removed when rename

Tags: java

```
String namePlaylist = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Playlist name :");
File inPlayList = new File(namePlaylist);
String newName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Playlist name :");//for new name
File newF = new File(newName);
inPlayList.renameTo(newF);
File x = new File(namePlaylist);
x.delete();
```

It will create and rename a file based on user input. But both of the file are still there after execution. I tried to use `delete()` but it does not work too.

Comment: The `File` class is notoriously hard to debug in such cases. You should avoid using it as much as possible. Use `Path` instead, and the methods from the `Files` class to copy and rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
String namePlaylist = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Playlist name :");
File inPlayList = new File(namePlaylist);
String newName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter new Playlist name :");
                 
                    File newF = new File(newName);
                    inPlayList.renameTo(newF);
                    inPlayList = newF;
```

Answer (score 1):

As denoted in the Java documentation

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure that the rename operation was successful.

So this method returns a `boolean`. You should check if the renaming either was successful or not.

In my opinion you should use [Files::move](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) instead.

Here is a small example on how to do it with Java NIO.2:

```
String namePlaylist = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Playlist name :");
Path playList = Paths.get(namePlaylist);
if (Files.exists(playList)) {
    String newName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Playlist name :");
    Path renamed = Paths.get(newName);
    try {
        Files.move(playList, renamed, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

With IO:

```
String namePlaylist = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Playlist name :");
File inPlayList = new File(namePlaylist);
if (inPlayList.exists()) {
    String newName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Playlist name :");
    File newF = new File(newName);
    if (!newF.exists()) {
        boolean succeeded = inPlayList.renameTo(newF);
        if (!succeeded) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Renaming failed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mimisya give it a try with NIO.2

Comment: Don't you use an IDE? I strongly recommend using one. Here you go: `import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;`

Comment: we are going to use IDE on next assignment. there's no way to use renameTo eh?

Comment: @mimisya provided an IO solution with a bunch of checks